# explicitly dispose NpgsqlParameters

Tags: c#, .net, npgsql

Do I really need to explicitly dispose of NpgsqlParameters?

Code I am using goes below:

```
using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "Select * from mytable where column1=:pcolumn1 AND column2=:pcolumn2";
                command.Parameters.AddRange(new NpgsqlParameter[2]{
                new NpgsqlParameter{ ParameterName="pcolumn1", Value=val1},
                new NpgsqlParameter{ ParameterName="pcolumn2", Value=val2}
                });

                using (var reader=command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        //read reader here
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NpgsqlParameter is inherited from DbParameter and ICloneable. Neither of these implement IDisposable so you don't need to dispose NpgsqlParameters.